# jQuery - Page with a ton of checkboxes, how to bind?

Tags: optimization, checkbox, jquery

I have a page of checkboxes, in some cases more than 100. I'm currently doing this:

```
$('form[name=myForm] input[name=myCheckbox]').change(function(){ 

    var numChkd = $('input[name=myCheckbox]:checked').size();

    console.log(numChkd);

};
```

But as you could imagine this can get wicked slow. Is there a better way to bind an event to multiple elements? This works, but I want to know if there is a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind an event to the parent container that will wrap all of the checkboxes and then check if the object that caused an event is a checkbox. This way you only bind one event handler. In jQuery you can use $.live event for this.

Comment: Awesome, I have worked with live but only for the purpose of binding to future elements (loaded via ajax). I'm guilty of never looking at delegate, so this worked perfectly. Also, +1 gnarf thanks for the linkage.

Answer (score 3):

Don't recount every time a checkbox changes. Just use a global variable, like this:

```
var CheckboxesTicked = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  CheckboxesTicked = $(":checkbox:checked").length;

  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      CheckboxesTicked += 1
    } else {
      CheckboxesTicked -= 1
    }
  });

});
```

Btw, the documentation states that you'd better use .length instead of .size() performance wise.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a container element (like a Div with no styling) and attach the event handler to the container.  That way, when the `change()` event happens on one of the checkboxes and percolates up the DOM, you'll catch it at the container level.  That's one way to make this faster.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). One binding on a parent element can replace all the individual bindings on the child elements. It's perfect for this situation (and also solves the problem of attaching behavior to dynamically-added elements, should the need arise).

```
$('form[name=myForm]').delegate('input[name=myCheckbox]','change', function(){
  var numChkd = $(this).siblings(':checked').length; // assuming siblings
  console.log(numChkd);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would approach it:

```
$('form[name=myForm]').each(function() {
  var $form = $(this),
      $boxes = $form.find('input[name=myCheckbox]');

  $form.delegate('input[name=myCheckbox]', 'change', function() { 
    var numChkd = $boxes.filter(':checked').length;
    console.log(numChkd);
  });

});
```

This takes advantage of caching the `$boxes` selection.  It will look for all the boxes when it sets up the event.  It uses [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) to attach an event to the `form` which will get fired anytime an child `input[name=myCheckbox]` creates a `change` event.  In this event handler, you can easily filter the already obtained list of checkboxes by which ones are `:checked` and get the `length` of the matched elements.  (The documentation for [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size) basically states there is no reason to ever use it... It just returns `this.length` anyway...)

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/F6xpD/) for a working demo

Answer (score 1):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kKUdm/

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      var value = $(this).val();
      console.log(name + ':' + value);
    }
   });
```

Comment: I would be quite surprised if `$(this).size()` actually returns the number of checked boxes. It should always return `1`, since the `change` handler runs in the context of a single DOM element.

Comment: it wont... you want `$('input:checkbox:checked').length`

Comment: `is()` returns a boolean, so you can't call `size()` on it. You were probably looking for `filter()`, but `$(this)` will only contain one element anyway, so that won't work either. Listen to @gnarf :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Var $chks = $(":checkbox");
Var ChkCount =0;
Var chktimer =0;
Function updateChkCount(){
      ChkCount = $chks.filter(":checked").length;
      $chks.end();
       // do something witb ChkCount
}
$chks.bind("check change", function(){
      clearInterval(chktimer);
      chktimer = setInterval("updateChkCount()",250);
});
```